# Maximal coss-correlation formula

Tags: cross-correlation

I'm reading "Comparing SVM and Convolutional Networks for Epileptic Seizure 
Prediction from Intracranial EEG" by Yann Lecun et al, and in the paper they present the following formula for maximal cross-correlation:

[image]

How is C_i(0) and C_j(0) computed?

Link to original paper is here:
http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/publis/pdf/mirowski-mlsp-08.pdf

Comment: Presumably $C_i(0)=C_{i,i}(0)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer in 2 minutes.

Your answer can be found in this document in the section A.3.1.  http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1388245704004638

As Glen_b said, it is $C_i(0) = C_{i,i}(0)$